# Rails form return false works using .submit() but not .on()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to submit a form with ajax, so I'm trying to disable its submission with `return false;`. When I use

```
$('#post_form').submit(function() {
```

`return false;` works fine. So what's the problem? Well, I don't want to bind to the `#post_form`. I want to use:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#post_form', function(e) {
```

But `return false;` doesn't work. `e.preventDefault();` completely fails too.
What's going on??

```
<%= f.button( :submit, name: "Post", title: "Post",
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs notice_submit', id: 'postbutt'
              ) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#post_form', function(e) { // return false; doesn't work
// $('#post_form').submit(function() { // return false; works fine
  if ( validatePostForm() ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'script'
    });
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // this doesn't do anything
  return false;       // neither does this
});
```

**EDIT**

I've just discovered that removing `remote: true` from the form gets it working, although I don't understand why:

```
<%= form_for(:post, url: :posts, method: :post,
                    html: { class: "notice_form", id: "post_form" }
                    # remote: true 
                    ) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that in you latter example the handler is not being attached at all, try adding an alert or console.log statement. This often happens with turbolinks if you don't pay attention to the differences in the page lifecycle.

Comment: The handler is being attached. An alert just before `return false;` does appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the e.preventDefault(); at the beginning of the function. This is to make sure that it runs, since something else within the function could prevent it from running if placed at the bottom.

Put in a console.log('test'); and open up your browser's debugging console to see if it actually triggers.
Alternatively, you can use alert('test'); to check.

Comment: I put e.preventDefault(); at the beginning and an alert at the end. The alert appears and the form still submits twice, which means preventDefault() is running but not working. Baffled.

Comment: This should explain a bit more about the remote: :true option: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for

There seems to be a bit of confusion as to why 'return false' will not cancel remote true submissions, as noticed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245535/onsubmit-return-false-is-ignored-if-remote-true-in-rails-4
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387092/remote-true-form-avoids-js-field-validation